# PHP / MySQL Error Querying Email Address

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to query an email address using the following statement, however after hours of trying to escape the string successfully I've accepted defeat.

The query I am using is: `SELECT id, email FROM user WHERE email = '$email'`

That gives me an error:

> MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1

I'm sure it's simple.. I just can't seem to find an answer anywhere that works.

**UPDATE #1**

The code that I have been using is:

`$email = "abc@gmail.com";`

`$sql = "SELECT id, email FROM user WHERE email = '$email'";`

`$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Unable to connect: '.mysql_error());`

**UPDATE #2**

The email comes from the Facebook connect API.

Comment: Please show the full generated query that you are using, and the PHP code

Comment: Also, where does that E-Mail address come from? User input?

Comment: The code you are showing is generating a syntax error (`abc@email.com` needs quotes). Can you show the exact code you are using? Also, please do a `echo $sql;` for the E-Mail address and show the result.

Comment: There's misprint in query string: SELET instead of SELECT.

Comment: `SELECT id, email FROM user WHERE email = 'abc@gmail.com'`

Comment: @lethal that's strange, in that case my answer below doesn't apply. It fails with `abc@gmail.com`, you are 1000% sure about that? This is real live data from Facebook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably because you the E-Mail address that you get from Facebook connect contains quotes, e.g. something like

```
"Harry"@gmail.com  
"Harry@gmail.com"
```

when pulling data from a web service (or from anywhere else), you *need* to escape the data to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection), and garbled queries like in your situation.

In your case:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
```