# Why I can't query emails? (JDBC / MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here's my "Estabelecimento" class:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Estabelecimento<T> {
    final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd_gopg"; // Mudar o host / endereço do banco de dados aqui.
    final String USER = "root"; // Mudar o usuário do banco de dados aqui.
    final String PASS = ""; // Mudar a senha do banco de dados aqui.
    T input = null;
    Integer fk = null;
    String searchKeyword = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    public Estabelecimento(T input) throws SQLException {
        this.input = input;
        if (this.input instanceof Integer || this.input.getClass().getSimpleName() == "Integer") {
            this.fk = (Integer) this.input;
        } else if (this.input instanceof String) {
            this.searchKeyword = (String) this.input;
        }
        try {
            Class.forName(this.JDBC_DRIVER);
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.DB_URL, this.USER, this.PASS);
        } catch(SQLException se) {
              se.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (this.searchKeyword != null) {
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT fk FROM email_estabelecimento WHERE nm_email = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, this.searchKeyword);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("No such email.");
            } else {
                while(rs.next()) {
                    this.fk = rs.getInt("fk");
                }
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getEmail() throws SQLException {
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT nm_email FROM email_estabelecimento WHERE fk = " + this.input.toString();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        String email = null;
        while(rs.next()) {
            email = rs.getString("nm_email");
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        return email;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAddress() throws SQLException {
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT nm_rua_estabelecimento, cd_numero_estabelecimento, nm_predio_estabelecimento, cd_apto_estabelecimento, ds_complemento_estabelecimento FROM endereco_estabelecimento WHERE fk = " + this.input.toString();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        ArrayList<String> address = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            address.add(rs.getString("nm_rua_estabelecimento"));
            address.add(rs.getString("cd_numero_estabelecimento"));
            address.add(rs.getString("nm_predio_estabelecimento"));
            address.add(rs.getString("cd_apto_estabelecimento"));
            address.add(rs.getString("ds_complemento_estabelecimento"));
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        return address;
    }

    public String getFacebookAddress() throws SQLException {
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT nm_link_facebook_estabelecimento FROM facebook_estabelecimento WHERE fk = " + this.input.toString();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        String email = null;
        while(rs.next()) {
            email = rs.getString("nm_link_facebook_estabelecimento");
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        return email;
    }

}
```

And here's my "Main" class:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Estabelecimento extra = new Estabelecimento("peixenabrasa@gmail.com");
        try {
            System.out.println(extra.getFacebookAddress());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see in the constructor, I'm using a prepared statement to query an email address. When I pass the email to the constructor inside the main function, I get the following MySQL error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1
```

Which is stupid, since I have **no** Syntax errors. [I've found that this is a common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042632/php-mysql-error-querying-email-address), but the examples I've found are for PHP.

EDIT:

I've updated the `getEmail()` method to use a prepared statement just as in the constructor, and the error persists.

```
public String getEmail() throws SQLException {
    String sql;
    sql = "SELECT nm_email FROM email_estabelecimento WHERE fk = ?";
    PreparedStatement stmt = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setInt(1, this.fk);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    String email = null;
    if (!rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("No such email.");
    } else {
        while(rs.next()) {
            email = rs.getString("nm_email");
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
    return email;
}
```

Comment: And you tried running the queries against the DB directly?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"? Without using a prepared statement? I've tried querying directly, and I get the same error. "near '@gmail.com'".

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to pass parameters to your queries. Use prepared statements with `?` placeholders, just like you're doing in your constructor.

Comment: Show us the structure of the table email_estabelecimento

Comment: what do you get if you launch the same query in MySQLWorkbench?

Comment: I've updated the question. I've updated the getEmail() method to use a prepared statement, and the error persists.

Comment: if the query works well in MySQLWorkbench, try to get the latest version of the jdbc driver as it could be due to a bug in the driver

Comment: By "directly", I mean either through a command line or a GUI to MariaDB.  Doing that as practice will identify whether it's your SQL or your Java code (or both).

Comment: I've tried to run the query on HeidiSQL and it worked. "SELECT fk FROM email_estabelecimento WHERE nm_email = 'peixenabrasa@gmail.com';"

Comment: [This is the version I have, I believe it's the latest one.](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html)

Comment: use the JDBC driver of mariaDB instead https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/

Comment: Thank you, I'll try with it.

Comment: I've tried with it, and I got the exact same error haha. Frustrating bug.

Comment: Also try `System.out.println(stmt);` to see what is getting prepared.  (YMMV depending on the JDBC driver.  MySQL is supported though not sure about MariaDB specifically.)  I checked, but don't see that `fk` is a reserved word.

Comment: @bphilipnyc, this is what is getting prepared. It looks just fine: `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@5a10411: SELECT fk FROM email_estabelecimento WHERE nm_email = 'peixenabrasa@gmail.com'`

Comment: It must have something to do with the '@' character. It makes no sense.

Comment: Do you still get an exception if you removed the `@` symbol?  Or the `WHERE` clause altogether?